# How to record audio and mux with video stream on Android with WebRTC?

Tags: android, audio, video, webrtc, android-audiorecord

I am working on WebRTC. My task is to record audio and video before call connect. I have recorded only video using VideoFileRenderer class. How can I record audio and mux with video using MediaMuxer?

This is a VideoFileRender class which I am using for recording and muxing.

```
package org.webrtc;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

import org.webrtc.audio.AudioDeviceModule;
import org.webrtc.audio.JavaAudioDeviceModule;
import org.webrtc.audio.JavaAudioDeviceModule.SamplesReadyCallback;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class VideoFileRender implements VideoSink {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoFileRender";
    private final HandlerThread renderThread;
    private final Handler renderThreadHandler;
    private final HandlerThread audioHandlerThread;
    private final Handler audioThreadHandler;
    private int outputFileWidth = -1;
    private int outputFileHeight = -1;
    private ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers;
    private ByteBuffer[] audioInputBuffers;
    private ByteBuffer[] audioOutputBuffers;
    private EglBase eglBase;
    private EglBase.Context sharedContext;
    private VideoFrameDrawer frameDrawer;

    // TODO: these ought to be configurable as well
    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";    // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
    private static final int FRAME_RATE = 30;               // 30fps
    private static final int FRAME_INTERVAL = 5;           // 5 seconds between I-frames

    private MediaMuxer mediaMuxer;
    private MediaCodec encoder;
    private MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo, audioBufferInfo;
    private int trackIndex = -1;
    private int audioTrackIndex;
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private GlRectDrawer drawer;
    private Surface surface;
    private MediaCodec audioEncoder;
    private AudioThread audioThread;


    //  private AudioThread audioThread;
    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;    // 44.1[KHz] is only setting guaranteed to be available on all devices.
    private static final int BIT_RATE = 64000;
    public static final int SAMPLES_PER_FRAME = 1024;    // AAC, bytes/frame/channel
    public static final int FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 25;    // AAC, frame/buffer/sec

    public VideoFileRender(String outputFile, final EglBase.Context sharedContext, boolean withAudio) throws IOException {
        renderThread = new HandlerThread(TAG + "RenderThread");
        renderThread.start();
        renderThreadHandler = new Handler(renderThread.getLooper());

//    if (withAudio) {
        audioHandlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG + "AudioThread");
        audioHandlerThread.start();
        audioThreadHandler = new Handler(audioHandlerThread.getLooper());
    /*} else {
      audioThread = null;
      audioThreadHandler = null;
    }*/
        bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        this.sharedContext = sharedContext;

        // Create a MediaMuxer.  We can't add the video track and start() the muxer here,
        // because our MediaFormat doesn't have the Magic Goodies.  These can only be
        // obtained from the encoder after it has started processing data.
        mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile,
                MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

        audioTrackIndex = withAudio ? -1 : 0;

        audioThread = new AudioThread();

    }

    private void initVideoEncoder() {
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, outputFileWidth, outputFileHeight);

        // Set some properties.  Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec
        // configure() call to throw an unhelpful exception.
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
                MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 6000000);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, FRAME_INTERVAL);

        // Create a MediaCodec encoder and configure it with our format.  Get a Surface
        // we can use for input and wrap it with a class that handles the EGL work.
        try {
            encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
            encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            renderThreadHandler.post(() -> {
                eglBase = EglBase.create(sharedContext, EglBase.CONFIG_RECORDABLE);
                surface = encoder.createInputSurface();
                eglBase.createSurface(surface);
                eglBase.makeCurrent();
                drawer = new GlRectDrawer();
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, e);
        }
        audioThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFrame(VideoFrame frame) {
        frame.retain();
        if (outputFileWidth == -1) {
            outputFileWidth = frame.getRotatedWidth();
            outputFileHeight = frame.getRotatedHeight();
            Log.d(TAG, "onFrame: " + outputFileWidth + " " + outputFileHeight);
            initVideoEncoder();
        }
        renderThreadHandler.post(() -> renderFrameOnRenderThread(frame));
    }

    private void renderFrameOnRenderThread(VideoFrame frame) {
        if (frameDrawer == null) {
            frameDrawer = new VideoFrameDrawer();
        }
        frameDrawer.drawFrame(frame, drawer, null, 0, 0, outputFileWidth, outputFileHeight);
        frame.release();
        drainEncoder();
        eglBase.swapBuffers();
    }

    /**
     * Release all resources. All already posted frames will be rendered first.
     */
    public void release() {
        isRunning = false;
        if (audioThreadHandler != null)
            audioThreadHandler.post(() -> {
                if (audioEncoder != null) {
                    audioEncoder.stop();
                    audioEncoder.release();
                }
                audioHandlerThread.quit();
                audioThread = null;
            });

        renderThreadHandler.post(() -> {
            muxerStarted = false;
            if (encoder != null) {
                encoder.stop();
                encoder.release();
            }
            eglBase.release();
            mediaMuxer.stop();
            mediaMuxer.release();
            renderThread.quit();
        });
    }

    private boolean encoderStarted = false;
    private volatile boolean muxerStarted = false;
    private long videoFrameStart = 0;

    private void drainEncoder() {
        if (!encoderStarted) {
            encoder.start();
            encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
            encoderStarted = true;
            return;
        }
        while (true) {
            int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 10000);
            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                break;
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                Log.e(TAG, "encoder output buffers changed");
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();

                Log.e(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat);
                trackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                if (trackIndex != -1 && !muxerStarted) {
                    mediaMuxer.start();
                    muxerStarted = true;
                }
                if (!muxerStarted)
                    break;
            } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
            } else { // encoderStatus >= 0
                try {
                    ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
                    if (encodedData == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                        break;
                    }
                    // It's usually necessary to adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo.
                    encodedData.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);
                    if (videoFrameStart == 0 && bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs != 0) {
                        videoFrameStart = bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs;
                    }
                    bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs -= videoFrameStart;
                    if (muxerStarted)
                        mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex, encodedData, bufferInfo);
                    isRunning = isRunning && (bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) == 0;
                    encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                    if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private long presTime = 0L;


    private class AudioThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (audioEncoder == null) {
                try {
                    final MediaFormat audioFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(MIME_TYPE, SAMPLE_RATE, 1);
                    audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
                    audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_MASK, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO);
                    audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
                    audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
                    audioEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
                    audioEncoder.configure(audioFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
                    audioEncoder.start();
                    audioInputBuffers = audioEncoder.getInputBuffers();
                    audioOutputBuffers = audioEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            try {
                final int min_buffer_size = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
                        SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                int buffer_size = SAMPLES_PER_FRAME * FRAMES_PER_BUFFER;
                if (buffer_size < min_buffer_size)
                    buffer_size = ((min_buffer_size / SAMPLES_PER_FRAME) + 1) * SAMPLES_PER_FRAME * 2;

                AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffer_size);
                if (audioRecord.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                    audioRecord = null;

                if (audioRecord != null) {
                    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SAMPLES_PER_FRAME);
                    int readBytes;
                    audioRecord.startRecording();
                    for (; isRunning; ) {
                        // read audio data from internal mic
                        buf.clear();
                        readBytes = audioRecord.read(buf, SAMPLES_PER_FRAME);
                        if (readBytes > 0) {
                            // set audio data to encoder
                            buf.position(readBytes);
                            buf.flip();
                            encode(buf, readBytes, getPTSUs());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void encode(ByteBuffer buffer, int length, long presentationTimeUs) {
        final ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = audioEncoder.getInputBuffers();

            final int inputBufferIndex = audioEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                final ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                inputBuffer.clear();
                if (buffer != null) {
                    inputBuffer.put(buffer);
                }
//              if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "encode:queueInputBuffer");
                if (length <= 0) {

                    audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, 0,
                            presentationTimeUs, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);

                } else {
                    audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, length,
                            presentationTimeUs, 0);
                }
            } else if (inputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // wait for MediaCodec encoder is ready to encode
                // nothing to do here because MediaCodec#dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC)
                // will wait for maximum TIMEOUT_USEC(10msec) on each call
            }

    }


    private long prevOutputPTSUs = 0;

    protected long getPTSUs() {
        long result = System.nanoTime() / 1000L;
        if (result < prevOutputPTSUs)
            result = (prevOutputPTSUs - result) + result;
        return result;
    }


}
```

I expect using scenario mp4 file will be created with audio and video, but it creates an mp4 file with only video.

Comment: You can use MediaRecorder provided by WebRTC and for merge use script@Ronit

Comment: I am not seeing MediaRecorder class anywhere in webrtc library. @Dhanshri

Comment: check this - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder

Comment: This MediaRecorder API is for chrome or Mozila. I am looking solutions in WebRTC SDK for Android.